# Parsing the following JSON response

Tags: apex, rest-api, inner-class

I need to parse the `PRIM_CITYAC`,`PRIM_STATEAC`,`PRIM_COUNTRY_NMAC` from the following response. I'm very new to REST API. I've create inner class with list in order to obtain the values. Now i got those values as expected. But I don't know how to parse the values from that.

Here is the response :

> FacetCounts:[facet_fields=FacetFields:[PRIM_CITYAC=(duluth, 2, portsmouth, 2, salisbury, 2, ann arbor, 1, avon, 1, ...), PRIM_COUNTRY_NMAC=(united states (the), 7, united kingdom (the), 4, australia, 1, uk, 1, korea (the republic of), 0, ...), PRIM_STATEAC=(il, 2, mn, 2, fl, 1, ma, 1, mi, 1, ...)]]

```
public class MainResponseWrapper{
    public ResponseHeaderWrapper responseHeader{get;set;}
    public ResponseWrapper response {get;set;}
    public FacetCounts facet_counts {get;set;} // New stuff
}



public class FacetCounts {  
    public FacetFields facet_fields {get;set;}
}
public class FacetFields {
    public List <String> PRIM_COUNTRY_NMAC {get;set;}
    public List <String> PRIM_CITYAC {get;set;}
    public List <String> PRIM_STATEAC {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Could we see the source JSON? This has got to be one of the worst JSON designs I've ever seen, if I'm reading this correctly...

Comment: does not look like valid JSON to me

Comment: @Eric I said the same thing, then I realized they'd already parsed it and are debugging the results...

Comment: A simple way to get the right classes generated (most of the time) is to paste an example of the JSON into https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.